# What happens to the RPM when I apply brakes to the wheel collider?

Tags: unity

I'm very new to Unity game development, and I am working on a car controller script in C#. What happens to the RPM when I apply brakes to the wheel collider? I do not know how to view the RPM changes.

Comment: well if he wants to know the rpm changes, and dosnt know how to see them you would simply tell him to write a line of code, that would show it as a debug console message. Also i think this is perfectly acceptable. He dosnt know how to see the rpm changes, i think this question gives us enough of an insight to answer.

Comment: @user6668201, to clarify, do you mean it is off topic because the user is "new to Unity", or because they do not show research effort? We consider *where to get started* questions off topic, but being new does not equate to "where to get started". Lack of research is a valid reason to *downvote*, but we do not *close* questions because of it.

Comment: @Astroboy, I am removing the language tag, as your question is not specific to any particular language in Unity. You seem to be asking how a particular element of a component works, not how a specific element of coding works. That said, UnityScript is the JavaScript variant found in Unity. For questions concerning C#, please use the [tag:c#] tag, to ensure the right people see your question.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to look at the Angular Velocity of the RigidBody your WheelCollider is connected to.

Angular Velocity is measured in radians per second.

One full revolution is equal to 2*PI, which is about 6.28 radians.

So your active RPM can be measured as follows:

```
float RPM = RigidBody.angularVelocity / 2PI / 60;
```